# how much work should we do in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, offloading

how much work should we do in the database?
Ok I'm really confused as to exactly how much "work" should be done IN the database, and how much work had to be done instead at the application level?

I mean I'm not talking about obvious stuff like we should convert strings into SHA2 hashes at the application level instead of the database level..

But rather stuff that are more blur, including, but not limited to "should we retrieve the data for 4 column and do a uppercase/concatenation at the application level, or should we do those stuff at the database level and send the calculated result to the application level?

And if you could list any more other examples it  would be great.

Comment: Do the 'database work' in the database; that is selecting and storing data efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you need.
I like to do my business logic in the database, other people are religously against that.

You can use triggers and stored procedures/functions in SQL.

**Links for MySQL:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-sql-stored-procedures.aspx
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html

**My reasons for doing business logic in triggers and stored proces**

Note that I'm not talking about bending the database structure towards the business logic, I'm talking about putting the business logic in triggers and stored procedures.

1. **It centralizes your logic**, the database is a central place, everything has to go through it. If you have multiple insert/update/delete points in your app (or you have multiple apps) you'll need to do the checks multiple times, if you do it in the database you only have to do the checks in one place.
2. **It simplifies the application** e.g., you can just add a member, the database will figure out if the member is already known and take the appopriate action.
3. **It hides the internals** of your database from the application, if you do all your logic in the application you will need intricate knowledge of your database in the application. If you use database code (triggers/procs) to hide that, you don't need to know every database detail in your app.
4. **It makes it easier to restucture your database**  If you have the logic in your database, you can just change a tablelayout, replace the old table with a blackhole table, put a trigger on that and let the trigger do the updates to the new table, your app does not even need to know the database has changed, this allows legacy apps to keep working unchanged, whilst new apps can use the improved database layout.
5. **Some things are easier in SQL**
6. **Some things work faster in SQL**
7. **I don't like to use (lots of and/or complicated) SQL code in my application**, I like to put SQL code in a stored procedure/function and try to only put simple queries in my application code, that way I can just write code that explains what I mean in my application and let the database layer do the heavy lifting.

Some people disagree strongly with this, but this approach works well for me and has simplified debugging and maintenance of my applications a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, its a good practice to expect only "`Data`" from the Database. Its upto Application(s), to apply Business/Domain Logic and make sense of the data retrieved. Its highly recommended to do the following things in the Application Layer:

1) Formatting Date
2) Applying Math functions, such as interpolation/extrapolation, etc
3) Dynamic sorting (based on columns)

However, situations sometime warrant few things to be done at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion application should use data and database should provide them and that should be clear separation of concerns. So database gives records sorted, ordered and filtered according to requested conditions but it is up to application to apply some business logic to that records and "convert" them into something meaningful to the user.

For example, in my previous company we worked on big application for work time calculations. One of obvious functionalities in this kind of application is tracking vacation days of employees - how many days employee has per year, how many he used, how many left, etc. Basically we could write some triggers and procedures that would update those columns automatically. So when employee had his vacation days approved amount of days he applied for is taken from his "vacation pool" and added to "vacation days used". Pretty easy stuff but we decided to make it explicit on application level and boy, very soon we were happy we did it that way. Application had to be labor law compliant and it quickly turned out that not for all employees vacation days are calculated equally and sometimes vacation day can be not so vacation day at all but that is beside the point. Had we put this "easy" operation in database we had to version our database with every little change to a vacation days related logic and that would lead us straight to hell in customer support field due to a fact that it was possible to update only application without a need to update database (except clear "breakthrough" moments where database structure was changed of course).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've found that many applications start with a straight-forward set of tables and then and handful of stored procedures to provide basic functionality. This works very well; it usually yields high performance and is simple to understand, it also mitigates any need for a complex middle-tier.

However, applications grow. It's not unusual to see large data-driven applications with thousands of stored procedures. Throw triggers into the mix and you have an application which, for anybody other than the original developers (if they're still working on it), is very difficult to maintain.

I will put a word in for applications which place most logic in the database - they can work well when you have some good database developers and/or you have a legacy schema which cannot be changed. The reason I say this is that ORMs take much of the pain out of this part of application development when you let them control the schema (if not, you often need to do a lot of fiddling to get it working).

If I was designing a new application then I would usually opt for a schema which is dictated by my application domain (the design of which will be in code). I would normally let an ORM handle the mapping between the objects and the database. I would treat stored procedures as exceptions to the rule when it came to data access (reporting can be much easier in sprocs than trying to coax an ORM into producing a complex output efficiently).

The most important thing to remember though, is that there are no "best practices" when it comes to design. It is up to you the developer to weigh up the pros and cons of each option in the context of your design.